# I accidentally deleted my .htaccess file how to get it back?

Tags: php, wordpress, cpanel

I started using wordpress with my website (through 000webhost) and then I realized that's not really what I want. Not at all. So I went through and deleted all the files. There was a .htaccess file (for Wordpress) and one called .htaccess_origional. I accidentally deleted the original one and now I'm stuck with a Wordpress one that won't work. It was a file with no restrictions or modifications. I remember that it only had one line. Does anybody know how to get it back? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to visit Settings > Permalink and save. It will re-generate the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create the initial `.htaccess` file configuration. Here is the initial `.htaccess` configuraiton

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Reference: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/create-default-wordpress-htaccess-file

Comment: OP wants the other one I believe

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I last used their service but if I recall correctly you can rebuild your webdir (or whatever it's called).

You'll have to search for this function in your control panel.

When you click this it will reset your server so BE SURE TO HAVE A BACKUP.